# How to type a generic variable and function that uses the same type?

Tags: typescript

I'd like something like

```
interface propType {
  value: T
  action: (value: T) => void
}
```

Where `T` is anything, but it has to be same for both `value` and `action`. Typing them as `any` doesn't work because it would allow a type mismatch.

Comment: Would you then make a generic interface, say `propType<T>`?

Answer (score 4):

You were almost there:

```
interface propType<T> {
  value: T
  action: (value: T) => void
}
```